# IllegalStateException showing in a Spring MVC Example using Tomcat 9

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat9

I am trying to create a simple home page based on Spring MVC with a link to login page, and in the login page, after typing in some text and submitting it, instead of arriving at a second page which should parse in the data entered into the input field through model container - I am getting an error. I am using Tomcat 9 for this project.

```
"Request processing failed; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single public
constructor found for interface
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest - and no default constructor
found either"
```

Here's the main controller class:

```
 package com.luv2code.springdemo;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    @Controller
    public class FormController {
    //method to show the form
    
    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm() {
        return "helloworld-form";
    }
    
    //method to show the page after submitting the form
    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm() {
        return "helloworld";
    }
    
    //read form data and read data to model
    
    @RequestMapping("/processFormv2")
    public String Stringoperation(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)throws Exception {
        //read request param from html
        String name = request.getParameter("empname");
        
        //add some string to it
        name = name.toUpperCase();
        //create some message
        String res = name + " works here!";
        //add message to model
        model.addAttribute("res",res);
        return "helloworld";
    }
    }
```

Here's the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

<absolute-ordering />

<!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

<!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

And here's the spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <absolute-ordering />

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

Here is mainmenu.jsp file -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<h2>Welcome to the JSP!</h2>
<hr> <a href="showForm">Login Page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is helloworld-form.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>JSP Form</head>
<body>
<form action="processFormv2" method="get">
<input type = "text" name="empname" placeholder="Enter your name 
here">
<input type="submit" name ="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is helloworld.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859- 
1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>After submitting</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>This is after you have submitted!</h3>
<br><br>
Student name : ${res}
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the error that I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single public constructor found for interface jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest - and no default constructor found either

And here's my folder structure:
[Click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj5b9.png)

Update:
The above code works fine for Tomcat7 which uses 'javax.servlet.http' for HttpServletRequest. However I'd like to know what changes does jakarta version needs, in order for the code to work as expected in Tomcat9.

Comment: Tomcat 9 does **not** use the `jakarta` namespace, but `javax`. Tomcat 10 uses `jakarta` (but you need Spring 6.x to use it).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz but I am using Tomcat9 only. Is this due to the fact that I am importing the HTTPServletReq from jakarta's lib instead of javax? (jakarta.servlet and javax.servlet both jar files are there in my classpath)

Comment: Yes, your imports are wrong. You can add [`jakarta.servlet-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/4.0.4) to your classpath (as provided dependency), but **only** version 4, not version 5. If you fix this, your editor will not suggest any `jakarta.*` import.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I see alright - this fixed this. Thanks!